# Is there a way to position page content UNDERNEATH or ON TOP OF a scrollbar?

Tags: css, scroll, scrollbar, scrollbars

I'm trying to emulate the CTRL+F functionality from Chrome that highlights matches on the page in the scrollbar, but for certain fields in a form. Using page offsets and percentages, I have blocks of color which correspond to the relative locations of those fields on the page.

In my prototype, the blocks of color sit to the left of the scrollbar. Ideally, they'd sit UNDERNEATH the scrollbar, and the scrollbar's track would be transparent so that it looks like they're part of the scrollbar track.

Can the default scrollbar be set to allow for overflow content to show underneath it (or allow page content to go over it)? I know this could be accomplished if I just rolled my own scroll, but I'd like to use the default ones provided by the browser if at all possible.

[**It's clearest if you just look at this Prototype.**](http://jsfiddle.net/JhdkV/9/)

**CSS:**

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 14px;
    height: 18px;
    background-color:transparent;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track,
::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece {
    background:none;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    height: 6px;
    border: 4px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    background-clip: padding-box;
    -webkit-border-radius: 7px;
    background-color: #333
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-button {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    display: none;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-corner {
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thought of rendering the matches on the trackbar similarly to what browsers do today before. The idea is simple by using `linear-gradient` background for the `::-webkit-scrollbar-track`. However I did not try implementing this. Right after reading your question, I've tried it and looks like it's not such easy.

You can use the `linear-gradient` background OK, but if you try rendering more than 1 match (a line), it sometimes can't be rendered (especially when the window's size is changed) and the line is not rendered smoothly. Such as this seems to be OK:

```
//render 2 lines, one is at 50px and the other is at 100px
background: linear-gradient(transparent 50px, red 50px, red 51px, transparent 51px,
                            transparent 100px, red 100px, red 101px, transparent 101px);
```

but it's not stable, as I said when you try resizing the window, at some size, some line won't be rendered (at least I tried on Opera). When the window's height is large, the line even becomes blurred (not sharp) and thicker. I don't really understand this, because the color stops are set fixedly (by `px`, not by `%`). This issue is even worse when the number of lines is larger. You have a `linear-gradient` with many corresponding color stops. That seems to be a neat way to solve the problem. Just because of the undesired issue, we can't use that approach.

**The new approach**: So I tried using multi-backgrounds feature instead. Each background just renders 1 line, the `background-size` is the same for all the background is just about `2px` height and the `background-position` should be different. Here is the equivalent code (to the above clean code) using this approach:

```
background: linear-gradient(red, red), linear-gradient(red, red);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: 100% 2px;
background-position: 0 50px, 0 100px;
```

The new approach of course requires that the browser has to support multi-backgrounds  features (looks like just IE8- do not support this cool feature).

So that's almost what you need to solve this problem. Now we need to find how to apply that style using script. We can't select a pseudo-element (or something like that) via script. We can just use the `window.getComputedStyle()` method to get the *read-only* style of a pseudo-element. However we always have a way to modify the CSS directly. That's is by using pure JS with the help of `document.styleSheets` and `cssRules`. They allow us to insert/remove/modify a rule.

That looks great. But there is still another issue. When changing the style using that method, the style is not applied right (at least it happens to the `::-webkit-scrollbar-track`, it may not happen to other elements). Only when you move the mouse over the scrollbar, the new style is applied. I've just found a simple way to *invalidate* that scrollbar by setting the `overflow` of `document.documentElement` (the `html`) to `hidden` and set it back to `auto`. That works almost well.

Here is the code:

```
var requiredTb = $(".required input");
var invalids = requiredTb;
var offsets = [];
//init offsets to highlight on the trackbar later
requiredTb.each(function() {
  offsets.push(($(this).offset().top)/document.body.scrollHeight * 100);
});
//find the rule  styling the -webkit-scrollbar-track
//we added in the CSS stylesheet, this is done just 1 time
var sheets = document.styleSheets;
var trackRule;
for(var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++){
  var rules = sheets[i].cssRules || sheets[i].rules;
  for(var j = 0; j < rules.length; j++){
    var rule = rules[j];
    if(rule.selectorText == "::-webkit-scrollbar-track:vertical"){
        trackRule = rule; break;           
    }
  }
}
//define an invalidate() method, we need to use this method 
//to refresh the scrollbars, otherwise the newly applied style is not affected
window.invalidate = function(){
  $(document.documentElement).css('overflow','hidden');
  setTimeout(function(e){
    $(document.documentElement).css('overflow','auto');
  },1);
};
//this is the main function to set style for the scrollbar track.
function setTrackHighlights(positions, color){
  positions.sort();//ensure that the input array should be ascendingly sorted.       
  trackRule.style.cssText = "";
  var gradient = "background: ", backPos = "background-position: ";
  var winHeight = $(window).height();
  $.each(positions, function(i,pos){
    gradient += "linear-gradient(" + color + ", " + color + "),";
    backPos += "0 " + pos + "%,"
  });  
  gradient = gradient.substr(0,gradient.length-1) + ";";
  backPos = backPos.substr(0,backPos.length -1) + ";";    
  trackRule.style.cssText += gradient + backPos + "background-repeat:no-repeat; background-size:100% 2px";

  invalidate();
}
//initially set the highlights on the trackbar
setTrackHighlights(offsets,'red');
//handle the oninput event to update the highlights accordingly
requiredTb.on('input', function(e){
  var required = $(this).closest('.required');
  var refreshHighlights = false;       
  if(this.value && !required.is('.ok')) {
    required.addClass('ok');
    refreshHighlights = true;
    invalids = invalids.not(this);
  }
  if(!this.value && required.is('.ok')) {
    required.removeClass('ok');
    refreshHighlights = true;
    invalids = invalids.add(this);
  }
  if(refreshHighlights){
    offsets.splice(0);
    invalids.each(function() {
      offsets.push(($(this).offset().top)/document.body.scrollHeight * 100);
    });
    setTrackHighlights(offsets,'red');
  }
});
```

You have to add an empty `::-webkit-scrollbar-track:vertical` rule (we need to deal only with the vertical scrollbar) in the CSS code, it should be appended at the last to override any similar rule before. We can in fact use the `insertRule()` method (of a CSSRuleList which can be accessed via `cssRules` property) to add a new rule instead of looping through the `styleSheets`, and through the `cssRules` (of each sheet) to find the empty rule `::-webkit-scrollbar-track:vertical`.

The code I posted here can be improved, such as you can add another method `setTrackHighlights` to allow to add more lines (instead of rendering all the lines each time we need to add/remove just 1 line)...

Note that by using the term ***line***, I mean the rendering representation of a match on the trackbar.

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JhdkV/13/)

Comment: Fantastic solution. I discovered that both yours and mine break for scrollboxes within a page. For example, two forms side-by-side, max-height:300px, overflow:scroll. I'd love to be able to use the same effect, but position:fixed on the scroll markers takes them out of the DOM flow.

Comment: @Jon anyway the point here is how to render the lines on the trackbar, the solution is using multi-backgrounds feature, each background is just `2px` height and just renders 1 line, using `background-position` to set where the line should be rendered. I think that mechanism is enough to solve any related issue, such as when focusing on a required field, the corresponding line on the trackbar should have a different color such as `yellow` (instead of `red`), ...